# Facebook login error Javascript

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I was using Facebook login without a problem.. But mysteriously the next error started to appear in the firebug console, and now I am unable to login.

(new Date).addMonths is not a function
FB.provide('',{getLoginStatus:function...signed_request,code'});return a;}}});

I'm using the Javascript SDK.

```
<div id='fb-root'></div>
  <script>
    //<![CDATA[
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
      appId      : '205160466168923', // App ID
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      oauth      : true, // enable OAuth 2.0
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
      });
      //channelUrl : '//www.clasesd.com/channel.html', // Channel File

      // Additional initialization code here
      };

      // Load the SDK Asynchronously
      (function(d){
      var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
      js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#**oauth=1**&appId=205160466168923&xfbml=1";
      d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
      }(document));
    //]]>
  </script>
```

And this is what I use to trigger the login

```
FB.login(function(response) {
if (response.authResponse) {
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
    console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
    window.location = redirect_url;
    });
} else {
    console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
}
}, {scope: 'email, offline_access, publish_stream, user_events'});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Known issue, see http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/149848578458727

As stated in the comments on that issues, this is a work around:

Place the following code before you call `FB.init()`

```
Date.prototype.addMonths = function(n) {
    this.setMonth(this.getMonth()+n);
    return this;
}
```